# Getting PendingIntent result from notification into target activity

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

In the `NotificationCompat.Builder` we pass the `PendingIntent` as setContentIntent(). Now what I want to do is that in the target activity I want the Intent object that was passed in the `PendingIntent` instance. So that I can get the extras of the Intent passed through PendingIntent.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The target `Activity` will be launched with the `Intent` that was passed to `PendingIntent`. You can get the "extras" from that. What is the problem? What have you tried? What isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Use **onNewIntent** inside targeted activity

```
 @Override
  protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
     super.onNewIntent(intent);
       // use this intent object
     }
   }
```

If still facing issue then use **PendingIntent** like this

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext, TargetActivity.class);
 notificationIntent.putExtra("abc", "123");
 notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
 PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, notificationId, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```